# Backup/Restore SQLite db file to/from location outsides app's storage

Tags: android, sqlite, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I've successfully backup my .db file from `file:///data/data/my.package.name/databases/data.db` into `file:///storage/sdcard0/data.db` using `fileEntry.copyTo()`, but have problem on restore db file back to app.

If I copy backup file to `file:///android_asset/www/` I got FileError error code 1000, and if I copy the file to `file:///data/data/my.package.name/databases/` directly, there is no error occurred, but my app still reading a empty database after restore done.

My restore db code:

```
function performDBRestore() {
  window.requestFileSystem(
      LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
      function(fileSystem) {
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
              "file:///storage/sdcard0/data.db",
              function(fileEntry) {
                  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(
                      "file:///data/data/my.package.name/databases/",
                      function(directoryEntry) {
                          fileEntry.copyTo(directoryEntry, "data.db",
                              function (fileEntry) {
                                  console.log("Restore success!");
                              },
                              function (error) { //no error, but db still empty while open
                                  console.log("Restore fail!");
                              }
                          );
                      },
                      function(error) {
                          // if I copy backup file to "file:///android_asset/www/",
                          // I got errCode 1000 here
                      }
                  );
              },
              function (error) {
                  //some error handling....
              }
          );
      },
      function(error) {
          //some error handling....
      }
   );
}
```

My open db code:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "data.db"});
```

By the way, if I copy backup file to `file:///android_asset/www/`, I've to open db like following right?

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "data.db", createFromLocation: 1});
```

Any idea? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found actually my code restored the data.db file, but I can't get the restored db data until I quit my app and re-launch it. I don't know why but anyway, the data.db did restored.